# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'TextClip' object has no attribute 'set_pos'

Tags: python

```
from pytube import YouTube
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance
from moviepy.editor import *
import requests, os


def downloadYouTube(preid):
    idv = preid
    urlPr = 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + idv + '/hqdefault.jpg'
    urlVideo = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + idv

    try:
        yt = YouTube(urlVideo)
    except:
        input('\nНеверный ID Видео. Для выхода нажмите Enter.')
        exit()

    print('Скачивание превью.')
    raw = requests.get(urlPr, stream=True).raw

    print('Уникализация превью.')
    image = Image.open(raw)
    image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(0.8))
    image = image.filter(ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(1.3))
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
    if not os.path.exists('./' + idv):
        os.makedirs('./' + idv)
    enhancer.enhance(1.5).save('./' + idv + '/preview.png')

    def downloadYouTube(videourl, path):
        yt = YouTube(videourl)
        author = yt.author
        title = yt.title
        description = yt.description
        tags = str(yt.keywords).strip('[]')
        tags = tags.replace("'", "")

        file = open('./' + idv + '/title.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(title)
        file.close()

        file = open('./' + idv + '/description.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(description)
        file.close()

        file = open('./' + idv + '/tags.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(str(tags))
        file.close()

        print('Скачивание видео.')
        yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
        yt.download(path, 'prevideo.mp4')

        if not os.path.exists('./' + idv):
            os.makedirs('./' + idv)

        print('Уникализация видео (занимает некоторое время).')
        video = VideoFileClip('./' + idv + '/prevideo.mp4')
        video = video.fx(vfx.lum_contrast, contrast=0.05)
        video = video.cutout(0, 2)
        text = TextClip(author, font='Purisa Bold', color='white', fontsize=30)
        text = text.set_duration(video.duration)
        text = text.set_pos('top')
        audio = video.audio
        audio = audio.fx(afx.volumex, 1.15)
        audio = audio.fx(afx.audio_fadein, 1.15)
        audio = audio.fx(afx.audio_fadeout, 1.15)
        video = video.set_audio(audio)
        final = CompositeVideoClip([video, text])
        final.write_videofile('./' + idv + '/video.mp4', threads=8, codec='libx264')
        video.close()
        final.close()
        os.remove('./' + idv + '/prevideo.mp4')

    downloadYouTube(urlVideo, './' + idv)


idv = str(input('\nID Video: '))
downloadYouTube(idv)
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sbork/PycharmProjects/YoutubeUnicalizator/main.py", line 79, in 
downloadYouTube(idv)
File "C:/Users/sbork/PycharmProjects/YoutubeUnicalizator/main.py", line 75, in downloadYouTube
downloadYouTube(urlVideo, './' + idv)
File "C:/Users/sbork/PycharmProjects/YoutubeUnicalizator/main.py", line 63, in downloadYouTube
text = text.set_pos('pot')
AttributeError: 'TextClip' object has no attribute 'set_pos'

Comment: try `with_position` instead of `set_pos` https://moviepy-tburrows13.readthedocs.io/en/improve-docs/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#moviepy.video.VideoClip.VideoClip.with_position seems like `set_pos` doesn't exist despite being mentioned in the docs

Comment: AttributeError: 'TextClip' object has no attribute 'with_position'

Comment: which version of moviepy do you have?

Comment: My version moviepy 2.0.0.dev2